# Map Index goes out of order after an inside Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6, async-await

```
sources.map(async (source, i) => {  
        
   console.log(i);  

   const level = await LevelsSourceModel.find({
       source: source._id.toString(),
       date: {$gte: date_timestamp} 
   }).limit(2).sort({date: -1})

   console.log(i)
})
```

As you can see above i'm mapping an array called sources, that array is the result of a mongoose find() callback parameter, which is bellow so you know where it's from.

```
  SourcesModel.find({
    building: ObjectId(`${buildingId}`),
    utility: "electricidade",
    'input.type': {
        $ne: "historic"
    } 
  }, async (err, sources) => {
```

The problem here are those console.log, the first one shows the correct and expected output:

[Correct Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uUKO.png)

The second shows all the indexes in a completely random order, each time I run the application the order changes :

[Incorrect Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu4aU.png)

Both console.log should have the same output and not different ones, the fact that the index is going out of order is affecting my whole application and can't find a solution for it, I rewrote the codes in many different ways but in the end it all comes to this problem.

Comment: You've marked the anonymous function as asynchronous, so you will have several running at the same time.  Was that not the intent?

Comment: @Joe the intent was for every "sources" , get the "levels" associated in the correct order, as you can see on the sources.map, there's i parameter which is the index, when I output the parameter before the find(), everything is sorted from 1 to 107 (which is the exact length of the array sources) but after the find() the output goes crazy 1, 2, 3 ,4, 5 , 10, 50, 32, 12 .... (keeping the same length) for example  and I don't understand why is that happening

Comment: But it is asynchronous, that means it will not wait for one call of the function to complete before initiating the second, and they will complete it whatever order they complete.  If you need them to be run serially to keep them in order, don't make the anonymous function asynchronous.

Comment: @Joe Meaning that everything will have to run sincronously correct? The problem is that every time I map a "sources", I need it to wait for the query (find) to be done on that "sources" so I the information is retrieved before the code completes, and according to mongoose documentation find() itself runs asynchronously

Comment: @Joe, I remade the code to make it work sincronously (even though find() works asyncronously), in other words I remove the async..await keywords, but unfortunately the behaviour hasn't changed